# Getting Speed Limits from HERE Reverse Geocode API

Tags: node.js, api, here-api

I'm using the reverse geocode endpoint from HERE to extract speed limits for a given latitude and longitude. I am including `linkInfo` in the `locationattributes` parameter and was getting speed limits in the results body but it is no longer showing up.

Here is an example of the endpoint being hit:
`https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}&prox=40.1245292,-74.8721781,50&mode=retrieveAddresses&locationattributes=linkInfo&gen=9`

Is this the correct method to get speed limits from HERE?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Geocoder API represents speedcategory in the response, which corresponds to different ranges of speed limit, that can be referred from below :

developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-speed-category.html

Response :

> LinkInfo: {
>   FunctionalClass: 5,
>   TravelDirection: [
>   "NW",
>   "SE"
>   ],
>   **SpeedCategory: "SC6"**,
>   LinkFlags: [
>   "Paved"
>   ],
>   AccessFlags: [
>   "Automobiles",
>   "Motorcycles",
>   "Buses",
>   "Taxis",
>   "Carpools",
>   "Pedestrians",
>   "Trucks",
>   "Deliveries",
>   "EmergencyVehicle",
>   "ThroughTraffic"
>   ]
>   }

Comment: Is it not possible to have the reverse geocode API return the speed limit type seen here:
`https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-speed-limit.html`
Or is there any other endpoint HERE offers that provides a speed limit given a coordinate on a street?